# Progressive Web Apps don't show link target

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-app

When I hover my mouse over a link in the Chrome browser, I can see at the bottom of the window the actual URL it would take to if I clicked the link.

However, if I use a progressive web app (PWA) on the same page (for example, the Microsoft Outlook PWA) and look at exactly the same page, if I hover over a link I don't see the target URL. This is a security risk, for example, when I receive an email from an unknown sender that contains links. I would like to be able to see the link URL before I click it. Is it possible to do this inside the PWA or do I have to go to Settings -> Open in Browser?

Comment: Related: [How can I open a file with a Chrome Web App?](https://superuser.com/q/1709604/152004), [How to see where a link REALLY points to in the status bar?](https://superuser.com/q/285627/152004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have being researching, apparently there isn't a built-in way to do force the status bar to be displayed when using a progressive web application (PWA). You might have to use a web browser extension or some sort of user customization (userscript, userstyle, etc.). You might have to keep using the normal web app.

---

Progressive Web Apps are intended to offer a fast web experience and similar look and feel in desktop and mobile. In order to achieve this, developers might make some changes compared to how the service is delivered through a normal web application, i.e. they might customize the status bar among other things.

To look at the specicific PWA settings click More > App Info. If it doesn't show the setting that you are looking, in the same menu click Settings.

Resources

- [Use Progressive Web Apps | Google Chrome Help Center](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9658361?hl=en)

Related

- [Firefox, show link URLs in status bar?](https://superuser.com/q/431268/152004) from 2012
  The only answer at this time has CSS code to customize the status bar.